# How can I display an Ampscript subtract output in currency format?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Am trying to do a simple ampscript sum where I can show a user how far they are from reaching the next level in spending status. Currently I am using this which outputs a successful sum:

```
%%[VAR @bought
SET @bought = AttributeValue("Total_Value_Bought__c")
VAR @gold
SET @gold = '2000000'
]%%

%%=Subtract(@gold,@bought)=%% from GOLD STATUS
```

I would like the sum to display as a currency though in the format of $X,000,000. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use FormatCurrency()

```
%%[VAR @bought
SET @bought = AttributeValue("Total_Value_Bought__c")
VAR @gold
SET @gold = '2000000'
SET @result = Subtract(@gold,@bought)
SET @formattedResult = FormatCurrency(@result, "en-US") /* Formats the number to USA's curreny unit - dollar. */
]%%

%%=v(@formattedResult)=%% from GOLD STATUS
```

**Check this out for further information:** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatCurrency.htm